# Difference between icontains and iregex in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am looking for solution of an usecase where i need to return search results even for part of a matching input text

> ex: if input text is **man** and the data that we have is ["manmohan", "manchester", "map"], then i should be returning ["manmohan", "manchester"]

i was searching across the net on how to implement it using django, and saw two probable methods, icontains and iregex

my questions here are

1. which suits my usecase?
2. what is the difference between these 2?

Answer (score 1):

The Main Difference beetween `__iregex` and `__contains`

- Both are lookups for filtering data from Queryset

##### __iregex

you can apply custom filter lookup for Queryset using regula expression) like this...

```py
    MyModel.objects.filter(t__iregex=r'X\d{6}-\d{4}[\da-z]{0,3}')
```

##### __icontains

it is a built-in Queryset lookup which is filter data using string-matching algorithms like this...

```py
    MyModel.objects.filter(t__icontains='man')
```

###### NOTE: - Two variant has in contains lookup

```
# ---------------- contains & icontains -----------------------
# the'i' in'icontains' means that case is ignored (icontains)
# o_data = Order.objects.filter(psize__contains='S') (case-sensitive required)
# o_data = Order.objects.filter(psize__icontains='s') (case-sensitive not required)
```